# convert dataset from json view .Net Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I am trying to create a chart in my angular application. for that I want to pass dataset as follows in my .Net Web API. [image]

But in my code it pass data set as follows

```
[{"Column1":1,"_Month":"January","SumOfMonth":-14900.40,"NoOfOutlets":11},{"Column1":2,"_Month":"February","SumOfMonth":-17856.00,"NoOfOutlets":2},{"Column1":3,"_Month":"March","SumOfMonth":-5312.00,"NoOfOutlets":4},{"Column1":4,"_Month":"April","SumOfMonth":-22103.13,"NoOfOutlets":15},{"Column1":6,"_Month":"June","SumOfMonth":-16014.72,"NoOfOutlets":5},{"Column1":7,"_Month":"July","SumOfMonth":-63251.93,"NoOfOutlets":46}
```

now I want to convert my dataset to the above format to create the graph.

my controller

```
public class MonthSelloutController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly VantageContext _context;
        public MonthSelloutController(VantageContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        //GET: api/AllSellOut
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Getset(string Year)
        {
            DataTable dt = new MonthSelloutMgt().Monthsellout(Year, _context);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            return json;
        }
    }
```

My BL

```
public DataTable Monthsellout(string Year, VantageContext _context)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                string conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("D_MonthSellOut", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Year", Year));

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

what I can do to convert my dataset as I mentioned in the above image. Any help is much appreciated.

result of my stored procedure
[image: result of my stored procedure]

Comment: What's the result of your SP?

Comment: I added it into my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to get a custom schema for your JSON string, you could try to write a class to carry your data from `DataTable` as below

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<List<object>> SumOfMonth { get; set; } = new List<List<object>>();
    public List<List<object>> NoOutlets { get; set; } = new List<List<object>>();
}
```

Then we can use `foreach` iterator data from DataTable and fill data in the `ViewModel`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Getset(string Year)
{
    DataTable dt = new MonthSelloutMgt().Monthsellout(Year, _context);
    ViewModel result = new ViewModel();
    
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            result.SumOfMonth.Add(new List<object>(){
            (decimal)item["SumOfMonth"],
            item["_Month"].ToString()
            });
        }
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            result.NoOfOutlets.Add(new List<object>(){
            (int)item["NoOfOutlets"],
            item["_Month"].ToString()
            });
        }        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    return json;
}
```

I would use [Sqldatareader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to read data result instead of `DataTable` becasue Sqldatareader migth provide higher performance then `DataTable`

Comment: sir, this returns empty set.  >       {"SumOfMonth":[],"NoOfOutlets":[]}

Comment: @Pra I had edit my answer on `foreach` part